# How can I group by and get the data based on conditions from multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

This is the 1st df which explains about the product data which are sold from different partners.

```
    Yearweek partner   homebrand businessunit phonememory_own Price_own  stock_age

 1. 202201   abc       brandown  phone1       64GB            490$       eol
 2. 202201   abc       brandown  phone1       128GB           600$       eol
 3. 202201   xyz       brandown  phone2       256GB           900$       new
 4. 202201   qwe       brandown  phone2       128GB           790$       new
 5. 202202   xyz       brandown  phone1       128GB           550$       old
```

say, I have multiple competitors for my phone whose data looks as below:

```
    Yearweek partner   otherbrand1 businessunit_ob phonememory_other1 Price_other1  stock_age

 1. 202201   abc       otherbrand  obphone1           64GB              390$       eol
 2. 202201   abc       otherbrand  obphone1           128GB             500$       eol
 3. 202201   xyz       otherbrand  obphone2           256GB             800$       new
 4. 202201   qwe       otherbrand  obphone2           128GB             590$       new
 5. 202202   xyz       otherbrand  obphone1           128GB             450$       old
```

Just the the second df, I have multiple other brand's data:

The output I am trying to get looks like this:
[output]

```
    Yearweek partner homebrand   businessunit  phonememory_own  Price_own  stock_age  otherbrand1  businessunit_ob phonememory_other1 Price_other1  stock_age

 1. 202201   abc     brandown    phone1          64GB              490$          eol   otherbrand    obphone1           64GB               390$       eol
 2. 202201   xyz     brandown    phone2          256GB             900$          new   otherbrand    obphone1           256GB              800$       new
 3. 202201   qwe     brandown    phone2          128GB             790$          new   otherbrand    obphone2           128GB              590$       new
 4. 202202   xyz     brandown    phone1          128GB             550$          old   otherbrand    obphone1           128GB              450$       old
```

The ouput is derived by this technique:
groupby [yearweek,partner,stock_age,phonememory],
for lowest phonememory_own and it's corresponding businessunit
map it's equivalent businessunit_ob,phonememory_other1, Price_other1

using row 1 and row 2 from both the dataframes, I have placed an output row 1 which corresponds for what I have explained above.

I am not able to get the logic right no matter how I group and try to aggregate the data.

Please help me with the above, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't `df1.join(df2, on='Yearweek')` create your desired output?

Comment: @NuriTaş
data should be grouped by [yearweek,partner,stock_age]
I am looking to get unique set of data for own phone's lowest memory the data from 2nd df should also have same [yearweek,partner,stock_age] and check what is the lowest memory, if it matches with the own phone's memory then merge and get that row as shown in the 3rd df above

Comment: Am I understand correctly that you only want lowest price rows from the 2nd df? I think you can first do `df2_mins = df2[df2.groupby(['yearweek', 'partner', 'stock_age'].price.idxmin()]`, and then do a `df1.merge(df2_mins, on=['yearweek', 'partner', 'stock_age'], suffixes=['_own', '_other'])`